# Paging can't remember checkbox status in Richfaces 4

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my Richfaces 4 extended datable has checkbox column. If I select some checkbox in one page, then move to another page of paginated table, then the selection I did on first page is gone. There is no selection on the first page.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to modify your `<h:selectBooleanCheckBox ... />` by `<h:selectBooleanCheckBox ... > <f:ajax render="tableID"/></h:selectBooleanCheckBox>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the @danRod's comments. Add  tag between  tag.